# How do I make hover for my ".pic" class to get effected?

Tags: sass

I want to add :hover this class ".pic".

So it can contain more description on .pic:hover

I use transform SASS,  width, and height on .pic:hover that seems not working.

I can't find out the problem.

Please help to find out my question.

Please watch it on my codepen for any details

```css
.pic
  width: 250px
  height: 250px


  //it doesn't get bigger when mouse is hovering over it
.pic:hover
  width: 400px
  height: 400px
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/leader285431/pen/mwaMZM?editors=0100)

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't formatted correctly. With CSS, make sure to surround everything with brackets {}. Also make sure to add a semicolon after every line in a class so it knows where to break it up. Change your code to the below and it'll work:

```
// Adding {} and ; fixed this issue
.pic {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.pic:hover {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: my apology, I used Sass as my preprocessor to transfer into CSS

Comment: Make sure to mark answered if helpful, the above worked for me! @ShawnXDoO

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/technological-background-with-circular-shapes_1035-4291.jpg" alt="pepsi" width="540" height="548">
  
  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>
```

Your code,

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  font-family: 微軟正黑體;
  position: relative;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#fc68d7, #8a3ab9, #bc2a8d, #cd486b, #e95950, #fbad50, #fccc63);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.camera {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  animation: ballUp 0.5s 1s both, ballDown 0.2s 1.5s ease-in both, cameraIn 0.3s 1.7s both;
  perspective: 500;
  -webkit-perspective: 500;
}

.lens {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 15px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: lensIn 0.3s 1.85s backwards;
}

.flashlight {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  animation: flashlightIn 0.3s 2.15s backwards;
}
.flashlight:after {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: flash 0.3s 2.45s both;
}

.pic {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #fff;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: picIn 1s 2.48s both, picFlip 1s 3.5s both;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pic:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
.pic img {
  max-width: 100%;
  
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


@keyframes ballUp {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 10%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
  }
}
@keyframes ballDown {
  0% {
    top: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
  }
}
@keyframes cameraIn {
  0% {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
  }
  80% {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
@keyframes lensIn {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
@keyframes flashlightIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes picIn {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes picFlip {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotateX(0deg);
    top: 100%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(360deg);
    top: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
}
@keyframes showImg {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="camera">
    <div class="lens"></div>
    <div class="flashlight"></div>
    <div class="pic">
      <div class="imgbox"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/technological-background-with-circular-shapes_1035-4291.jpg" alt=""/></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>This is my memory</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or zoom out with text inside,

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  font-family: 微軟正黑體;
  position: relative;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#fc68d7, #8a3ab9, #bc2a8d, #cd486b, #e95950, #fbad50, #fccc63);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

h5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.camera {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  animation: ballUp 0.5s 1s both, ballDown 0.2s 1.5s ease-in both, cameraIn 0.3s 1.7s both;
  perspective: 500;
  -webkit-perspective: 500;
}

.lens {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 15px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: lensIn 0.3s 1.85s backwards;
}

.flashlight {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  animation: flashlightIn 0.3s 2.15s backwards;
}

.flashlight:after {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: flash 0.3s 2.45s both;
}

.pic {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #fff;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: picIn 1s 2.48s both, picFlip 1s 3.5s both;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pic:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.65);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
  transform: scale(0.65);
}

.pic img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

@keyframes ballUp {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 10%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
  }
}

@keyframes ballDown {
  0% {
    top: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes cameraIn {
  0% {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
  }
  80% {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@keyframes lensIn {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes flashlightIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes picIn {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes picFlip {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotateX(0deg);
    top: 100%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(360deg);
    top: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
}

@keyframes showImg {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="camera">
    <div class="lens"></div>
    <div class="flashlight"></div>
    <div class="pic">
      <div class="imgbox">
        <h5>
Tech-Background
</h5>
        <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/technological-background-with-circular-shapes_1035-4291.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>This is my memory</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to make it bigger and contain more information such as some text on the bottom of the picture. So I need to make this class, ".pic:hover" bigger when I hover on it. But it seems not working. And I don't know the problem it is. Thank you

Comment: your question is not very clear. do u mean u want to zoom out? and have text inside?

Comment: I want to make it ".pic" 's width and height bigger and also the picture. so there can be enough space to put the description. Sorry for my bad expression in English

Comment: see 3rd snippet. are you looking to make the div bigger with the image?

Comment: yes but somehow I change "animation: picIn 1s 2.48s both, picFlip 1s 3.5s both;" into "animation: picIn 1s 2.48s backwards, picFlip 1s 3.5s"
and the hover's width and height change work. I don't know why. 
Maybe it's the problem? Do you know why is that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is wrong css. You have to use curly braises and semi colons as well.

```
.pic{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.pic:hover{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```